# JQuery: how to convert the below string into following date format?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am new to JQuery.I need to convert the below string into following dateTime format.How to achieve this?

string value:

```
 var w = "/Date(1388514600000)/"
```

Expected Date format Example:-

```
"Wed Jan 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
```

I need to achieve above without jQuery DatePicker UI and anyother UI?

Is this possible to achieve my Expected value in given string?

i am tried like this:-

```
 var d=date.parse(w);
 console.log(d);

 output:-
 NaN
```

Any help or an idea will be more helpful?

Thank you.Please give me a suggestion!

how to achieve above in JQuery?

Comment: *"how to achieve above in JQuery?"* - You don't, because jQuery doesn't provide date manipulation functions. You use plain JavaScript, or you use a date library. The output format you want seems to be just standard `Date` object `.toString()` format, so the problem is really just how to parse your input. See the linked duplicate question.

Comment: Edits are not supposed to *completely change your question*. They are meant to add additional information, make clarifications, and improve grammar/formatting. If you have a new question, then ask a new question.